# Data from Asynctask won't carry over to onCreateView for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

So my problem is that I can generate the data in the AsyncTask, but I can't get the data to transfer back to the onCreateView. This is my first dive into fragments. Sorry if my code's ugly, I'm just trying to get this to work, and also I'm quite new to Android programming, so sorry if I made a stupid mistake somewhere. I'm not sure if I need to post my global variables. And I know some of my variables are weirdly named.

onCreateView portion

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news,
            container, false);
    pb = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    gv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    swp = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);

    gv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    gv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    swp.setEnabled(false);

    hadapter = new NewsExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), m_hparts);

    System.out.println(m_hparts.size());
    gv.setAdapter(hadapter);
    return view;
}
```

RecyclerView adapter

```
public class NewsExpandableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsExpandableAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public ImageView messageButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            messageButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Model> mContacts;

    public NewsExpandableAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> contacts) {

        this.context = c;
        mContacts = (ArrayList<Model>) contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsExpandableAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsExpandableAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Model contact = mContacts.get(position);

        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(contact.getTitle());

        ImageView image= viewHolder.messageButton;

        Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(contact.getLink())
                .into(image);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }
}
```

Fragment XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sample">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

AsyncTask

```
public class Directory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String desc;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url + dateFormatYear.format(date)).get();

                listing_latest = document.select(".title.page_title");

                for (Element listing0 : listing_latest) {

                    Element hmonth = listing0.select("h3").first();
                    if(hmonth.text().equals(dateFormatMonth.format(date))){
                        month = hmonth.text();
                        hname = hmonth.parent().parent().parent().nextElementSibling();
                        releaseList = hname.select(".base_header.tc.m6");
                        for(Element block : releaseList){
                            name = block.select(".one_line.fs11 a").first();
                            image = block.select(".base_inner.h244.loading a img").first();
                            if(name != null){
                                hn = name.attr("title");
                            }
                            if(image != null){
                                hi = image.attr("abs:src");
                            }
                            m_hparts.add(new Model(hi));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            hadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            m_hparts.add(new Model(hi));
        }
    }
```

Edit: I put the `new Directory().execute();` in the `onCreate()` Still could not get data.

Comment: See my edit, and I added the edit to the `onPostExecute`

Comment: do not keep activity's objects in fragment: "pb" and "swp". Fragment can be reused with wnother activity. If you need them - call getActivity() right where you need those objects. note that in some cases getActivity can return null (if a fragment is detouched from activity). Or you can write to pb and swp in  onAttach(Activity activity) and set them to null in  onDetach()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add all of the new items to the data source, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the data source has been updated.

Make the return value of `doInBackground()` a list of your items, and return it to `onPostExecute()`.  You will need to change the parameters of the AsyncTask generics and the parameter passed into `onPostExecute()` as well.

Assuming your data source looks like this:

```
List<Model> m_hparts = new ArrayList<>();
```

You could do something like this:

```
public class Directory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Model>> {
    String desc;

    @Override
    protected List<Model> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //added:
        List<Model> parts = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url + dateFormatYear.format(date)).get();

            listing_latest = document.select(".title.page_title");

            for (Element listing0 : listing_latest) {

                Element hmonth = listing0.select("h3").first();
                if(hmonth.text().equals(dateFormatMonth.format(date))){
                    month = hmonth.text();
                    hname = hmonth.parent().parent().parent().nextElementSibling();
                    releaseList = hname.select(".base_header.tc.m6");
                    for(Element block : releaseList){
                        name = block.select(".one_line.fs11 a").first();
                        image = block.select(".base_inner.h244.loading a img").first();
                        if(name != null){
                            hn = name.attr("title");
                        }
                        if(image != null){
                            hi = image.attr("abs:src");
                        }
                        //m_hparts.add(new Model(hi));
                        //do this instead:
                        parts.add(new Model(hi));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return null;
        //do this instead:
        return parts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Model> parts) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for (Model h: parts) {
            m_hparts.add(h);
        }

        hadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```